# How to ensure I can't add in integers or any numbers into an array via user input for ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, exception, integer

I'm trying to create an array that only allows strings to be passed through, no numbers at all. Is there a way to make this possible?

I've tried the below expecting that if an integer got through then it raise an error, however I forgot that the 'gets' method converts everything into a string.

```rb
    exercise_list = []
    loop do 
        exercise_input = gets.strip.capitalize
        if exercise_list.include?(exercise_input) == false && exercise_input.is_a?(Integer) == false 
            exercise_list << exercise_input
            p exercise_input.class
        else exercise_input == "quit"
            break
        end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of `exercise_input` returned from `gets.strip.capitalize` is always a string. Even if "1" is entered, it will just be the string "1". Checking if it `.is_a?(Integer)` will always be false.

This is why it is not working, however, making it work depends a little on your requirements. What is an integer?

"1" obviously is, but what about "1 2", "1 a", "1 ", " 1", "1.1", "1,1", "0x1a", "01".

If you want to ask ruby to decide for you, you can try converting it to integer by calling `Integer(exercise_input)`and rescue the error if it's not an integer.

Otherwise I suggest you use a regex to check that the string contains what you want expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

When working with strings, Regex can be really helpful.
So, you have an input that is always a string. Eg. "asd12" so you can ask if inside the string there is a number, if there is, you pass to the next input, if not you append it to the array.

In elseif statement you are asking if there is a match with any digit number (/\d/), if there is, you pass to the next iteration.

Here is a website where you can practice regex: [www.rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com)

Here is my code

exercise_list = []

```
loop do
  print ">. "
  exercise_input = gets.strip.capitalize
  if exercise_input == 'Quit'
    break
  elsif exercise_input.match?(/\d/)
    next
  else
    exercise_list << exercise_input
  end
end
pp  exercise_list
```

I hope you can find it helpful.

PD. print (">. ") its just for visualization